# How to make a re-usable method of type T

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method as below

```
List<Customer> GetCusts = dataContext.Customers;
```

The customers table has a field called `IsValued` so i can do something like this

```
foreach (var c in GetCusts)
{
  if(c.IsValued)
    {
     // do something
    }
}
```

I have a products table doing the exact same thing also with the same column name

```
List<Product> GetProds = dataContext.Products;

foreach (var p in GetProds)
{
  if(p.IsValued)
    {
     // do something
    }
}
```

I thought to turn this into a Generic method (or better a class), so i can pass in a generic list a bit like

```
foreach (var p in GetData) // GetData could be a List<t> but of course i cant cast it. 
{
  if (p.IsValued)
     {}
}
```

but of course `IsValued` does not exist. I know the reason why (due to it being a generic type) but after researching around to see if its possible i couldnt get a decent example and test it out or maybe i just didnt understand. Can anyone advise how this could be possible or lead me to an article to achieve this?

**Edit 1**

My attempt so far in a class, it could be wrong but to give an idea in case im on the wrong path. I assume i need a property of IsValued (which doesnt have to be of a bool value) in the GenericValue class?

```
public interface ICustomGenerics<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetData();
}

public class GenericValue<T> : ICustomGenerics<T> where T : class
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        _entities.
    }
}
```

Comment: Nowhere have you shown your method signature.

Comment: `Customer` and `Product` need to both implement the same interface, or be derived from the same base class, where that interface/base class defines the property `IsValued`

Comment: What canton said, or, if that's not an option, make your function more general by allowing an `IEnumerable<T>` so it's up to the caller to do the filtering first (by chaining a `.Where`), or, if you do want it more specific than that, allow passing in a `Func<T, bool>` to get the value of `IsValued`, or use reflection to get at the `IsValued` property, or use `dynamic` -- roughly in decreasing order of appropriateness, safety and performance.

Comment: @canton7 Thanks, do you have a simple code snippet or a link i could use for an example? I checked W3 schools and although i got the understanding of it im struggling to put this together?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can use an `interface`:

```
public interface IValued {
    bool IsValued { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : IValued {
    public bool IsValued { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IValued {
    public bool IsValued { get; set; }
}

public void filterData<T>(List<T> data) where T: IValued {
    foreach (var d in data) {
        if (d.IsValued) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that in the interface, the `IsValued` could be declared read-only (`bool IsValued { get; }`) if we only need to have a common interface for reading the property. The implementing classes can still have setters.

Comment: Would it also work if we declared the filtering function as `public void filterData(List<IValued> data)` instead of using a generic argument?

Comment: @Orion, no because `List<Customer>` and `List<Product>` are not assignment compatible to`List<IValued>`. However, you could declare the parameter as `IEnumerable<IValued>`, because `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant.

Comment: @Orion Also depending on what you are actually doing with the members of the `List`, any other properties you need to access to process will need to be in the common Interface (which will need an appropriate name).

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out you can either pick a base class and derive from that, or you can use an interface. I'd rather go with the interface in this case.

Assuming you are using Entity Framework, you can use a partial classes to apply your interface:

```cs
public interface IValuable
{
    bool IsValued { get; set; } 
}
```

and you'd have partial classes like:

```cs
public partial class Customer : IValuable
{
   // IValuable implementation
   public bool IsValued { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public partial class Product : IValuable
{
   // IValuable implementation
   public bool IsValued { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can have a processor / service class that accepts these as generics with a condition that they should all implement this interface:

```cs
public class Processor<T> where T : IValuable
{
    public Something Process(T parameter)
    {
         foreach (var p in GetData) 
         {
            if (p.IsValued)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Since you declared your generic to have `IValuable` implementation, the code below will know `IsValuable` is a member.

I suggest this approach over base classes because interfaces are best used this way to define common behaviour. You can even see the same pattern in the framework, `IDisposable` (which implements Dispose()) and `IEnumerable` / `IEnumerator` (which implements things like GetEnumerator(), MoveNext() etc) are two most common examples.

Comment: Yes im using EF and the value i am checking (IsValued) is the same name of the column in my table. If i create the same name i get the error The type 'Customer' already contains a definition for 'IsValued' but if i change the name all is fine but it creates a new column with that name. All i would like to do is compare a column name value?? For now i am going to try to return the Field name inside the newly created property in the partial class but not sure if thats the correct approach?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you have `IsValued` property both on your original EF model and this partial model too - if that's correct, can you remove the one in your model and try again?